# Issue with emojis on a tomcat web application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, emoji

I am having an issue with storing emojis in the database. I have a tomcat web application hooked up to an RDS Mysql database (5.5+ version) So basically whenever there is an emoji, hibernate raises an exception

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [pojos.hibernate.Comment]

and the cause is

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: \xF0\x9F\x98\x80\xF0\x9F...' for column 'text' at row 1

This is hibernate connection configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate. connection. driver_class">com. mysql. jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXX:3306/XXXXXX?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXXXXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXXX</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

This is the table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `idcomment` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2936 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

I am trying to store emojis in the text column but no luck.

I have also tried to remove `autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8` from the connection string and kept the other properties but it didn't work. I also changed the database and all tables encodings to utf8mb4 but got the same error.

I have looked all over  but no luck. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it came from the fact that the connexions between my webapp and mysql were not established using utf8mb4. I put the following lines in my `my.cnf` and it worked!

Let me know if it works for you!

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = TRUE
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: In fact, that was all set server side. The issue with the connection string. I just need to remove `?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8`  and add
`  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
` to hibernate configuration